# Add co-ordinates to each pixel in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to add coordinates to each pixel of an image for this I am doing the following

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('images/0001.jpg')
grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

np_grayscale = np.array(grayscale)

# make the array 3d
processed_image = np_grayscale[:, :, np.newaxis]

x = 0
y = 0
for pixel_line in reversed(processed_image):
    for pixel in pixel_line:
        pixel = np.append(pixel, [x, y])
        x += 1
    y += 1

print(processed_image)
```

But this does not seem to work because I am still getting the original array that is in the form

```
[[[255]
  [255]
  [255]
  ...
  [255]
  [255]
  [255]]

 ...
...
  ...
  [255]
  [255]
  [255]]]
```

Moreover I don't think this is the most efficient way of doing this because I read that append creates a new copy of the array, can someone please help

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you try to achieve. The cv image you have already "has coordinates" of some sort. So you can already access the pixel at position (200, 500) by simply calling `greyscale[200, 500]`.

Comment: suppose the image is initially of shape (500, 100). Now I will divide the image into two parts (suppose two equal parts) so now image will be represented as two arrays of shape (250, 100) each. So I want to append the coordinates of each pixel so that after division I can retrieve the original coordinators of the pixel

Comment: Seems like it would be far easier and more performant, to just tweak the way on how you access your data, instead of assigning additional coordinate parameters to your image.

Comment: I agree with @Noltibus 's last comment. Just manage the way you are processing and storing the images after the split. Moreover, if you add coordinates, you will not be able to visualize the images as they will not be read as images by OpenCV. Although, there is another way you can do this. I'll be sharing it as an answer below.

Comment: if you have an image in uint8 format, tha max value is 255, be careful

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mesh of indices using `meshgrid()` and `stack()` them with the original image:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.asarray([
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 255, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
])

indices = np.meshgrid(
    np.arange(x.shape[0]),
    np.arange(x.shape[1]),
    sparse=False
)

x = np.stack((x, *indices)).T

# array([[[  0,   0,   0],
#         [  0,   0,   1],
#         [  0,   0,   2],
#         [  0,   0,   3]],

#        [[  0,   1,   0],
#         [  0,   1,   1],
#         [255,   1,   2],
#         [  0,   1,   3]],

#        [[  0,   2,   0],
#         [  0,   2,   1],
#         [  0,   2,   2],
#         [  0,   2,   3]],

#        [[  0,   3,   0],
#         [  0,   3,   1],
#         [  0,   3,   2],
#         [  0,   3,   3]]])

x[0, 0, :] # 0, 0, 0
x[1, 2, :] # 255, 1, 2
x[-1, -1, :] # 0, 3, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use [`xarray`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/).**

The easiest way, by far, to add coordinates to a NumPy array is with an [`xarray.DataArray`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#dataarray).  For example, here's how you can add coordinates that are just row and column index:

```py
import xarray as xr

data = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
rows, cols = data.shape
xs = np.arange(cols)
ys = np.arange(rows)
da = xr.DataArray(data, name="mydata", coords=[ys, xs], dims=['y', 'x'])
```

This `da` thing is a `DataArray`, which is essentially an indexed array ('indexed' in a `pandas` sense: the indices can be integers, floats, dates, etc). It has some nice features (try `da.plot()`). Otherwise, it basically behaves like a NumPy array. For example, you can slice it like a normal array:

```py
>>> da[:, 3:]
<xarray.DataArray 'mydata' (y: 5, x: 2)>
array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 8,  9],
       [13, 14],
       [18, 19],
       [23, 24]])
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) int64 0 1 2 3 4
  * x        (x) int64 3 4
```

As you can see, this subarray 'knows' its own coordinates. What's more, you can have as many dimensions as you want, and each axis can have multiple coordinates. It's very useful.

As others pointed out, you can probably achieve what you want with careful indexing alone, but if you really want coordinates this is how I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a grayscale image, you can convert it to the 3-channeled image in which the first channel will contain the pixel values, and the other 2 channels will contain the coordinates. So, if you split your image into two or more, you will still have the coordinates of the original image in the other two channels, and also to visualize the image, you can simply use only the first channel. Here's how you can do this.

```py
processed_image = np.zeros((grayscale.shape[0], grayscale.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint64)
processed_image[:, :, 0] = np.asarray(grayscale, dtype=np.uint64)

for i in range(processed_image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(processed_image.shape[1]):
        processed_image[i][j][1] = i
        processed_image[i][j][2] = j

print(processed_image)

# Displaying the image
cv2.imshow("img", np.array(processed_image[:, :, [0]], dtype=np.uint8))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Note:** Take care of the datatypes of the numpy arrays. You cannot store the coordinates of the complete image in the `np.uint8` array as it will only contain values from 0-255. Also, while displaying, you'll have to convert the first channel back to the `np.uint8` datatype as OpenCV only understands images in this format (for integer pixel values). That is why I have used an array of `np.uint64` datatype to store pixel values.